# SQL Server: varbinary or int to store a bit mask?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, bitmask

Is there any advantage of using int vs varbinary for storing bit masks in terms of performance or flexibility.

For my purposes, I will always be doing reads on these bit masks (no writes or updates).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should definitely use an `INT` (if you need 32 flags) or `BIGINT` (for 64 flags). If you need more flags you could use [`BINARY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) (but you should probably also ask yourself why you need so many flags in your application).

Besides, if you use an integral type, you can use standard [bitwise operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) directly without converting a byte array to an integral type.

If you do need more flags and have to use `BINARY` you lose native support for bitwise operators and therefore easy support for checking flag values. I would probably move checking for flag values to a client application but if you're comfortable programming in T-SQL that's an option as well. If you're using C# you have a [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class with the necessary operations and in Java you have a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class.

Comment: yeah, or event the smaller types like tiny int for smaller bit masks? I have never used a tiny int as bit mask yet, but should be no issue. int's work great.

Comment: How can we use varbinary when we have, for example, 100 flags? Can varbinary be used as flexible as int or bigint? It is not possible to make bitwise operation on two varbinary. How can we imitate the int-flag behaviour?

Comment: I'd use a `BINARY(13)` for this (has room for 104 bits/flags). However, you loose native support for bitwise operators. I updated my answer to provide some options.

Answer (score 6):

It is generally considered preferable to use a bunch of bit columns instead of a bit mask. They will get packed together in the page, so they won't take any more room. Although I too always seem to go with an int or bigint column to avoid all of the column name typing.. but with intellisense I would probably go with the bit columns.

Comment: I disagree, bitmasks still have their place and they are a great way to leave your options open without having to refactor your DB and SELECTS/VIEWS/SPROCS just to add a simple bool, they are very flexible ... just most programmers dont understand what they are these days

Comment: Programmer ignorance sometimes shows we're making good progress abstracting low-level optimizations away inside engines and frameworks.  INDIVIDUAL BIT FIELDS:  1. Are handled efficiently by the engine (packed together, manipulated by native code rather than TSQL).  2. Have meaningful names making your queries more understandable (rather than using arbitrary bit index numbers).  3. Can have indexes placed on them, accelerating queries. 4. Can have individually configurable default values.  5. Are easier to refactor to a larger type later if you decide the field needs more than two states. etc.

Comment: Exactly. Bitmasks in SQL just kill what SQL can do - you will never be able to query them efficiently. Ergo they should not be used.

Comment: There's at least one circumstance where a bitmask field is necessary: an index is limited to 16 columns, which you may exceed with a group of flags or a series of packed values.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades that limitation is just for the columns that make up the key of the index (you can add the bits as include columns and still predicate on them). Have you experienced cases where it was useful to have more than 16 booleans in the key of an index?

Comment: @ahains: No, but I've had instances where I wanted to make a key on more than 16 fields - including seven small integers.  I ended up packing the seven as three bits each in a single 32-bit `INT`.  Works great.  Certainly an unusual case, but valid.

Comment: @Triynko Column names are not necessarily a substitute for a proper business definition of a column's content.  Also, sometimes you're dealing in collections of bits from an external system (e.g. NTFS file-system ACEs) and it's easier to keep them that way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, considering an int has less storage space and is generally a little easier to work with I'm not sure why you'd use a varbinary.

Answer (score 1):

I usually agree with @hainstech's answer of using bit fields, because you can explicitly name each bit field to indicate what it should store.  However I haven't seen a practical approach to doing bitmask comparisons with bit fields.  With SQL Server's bitwise operators (&, |, etc...) it's easy to find out if a range of flags are set.  A lot more work to do that with equality operators against a large number of bit fields.

Comment: Except... hat bitwise operators FORCE A TABLE SCAN which kills performance while indivitual bit fields can efficiently be queried.